# Dividers fade in and out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu of 7 elements. Whenever an element is clicked, its content appears by fading in. If another element is clicked, the current content fade out and the new content fade in.
I applied the concept to 3 of the 7 elements in my menu, however i'm facing 2 problems:
1) A isn't fading in
2) There's a timing problem in fading in and out, where a content might collide with another.
Any help?

HTML:

```
<div id="menu" class="menu">
        <ul class="headlines">
             <li id="item1"onclick="checklist(this)"><button >A</button></li>
            <li id="item2"><button >B</button></li>
            <li id="item3"><button >C        </button></li>
            <li id="item4"><button>D         </button></li>
            <li id="item5"><button>E   </button></li>
            <li id="item6"><button>F       </button></li>
            <li id="item7"><button>G       </button></li>
<!--                  <li> <input type="button" value="animation" OnClick="checklist(this)"> </input>
  </li>-->
        </ul>
        </div>


        <div id="first">
<img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image10"src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
</div>


        <div id="second">
        <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image10"src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
    </div>

        <div id="third">
        <img id="image1" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image2" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image3" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image4" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image5" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image6" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image7" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image8" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image9" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<img id="image10"src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#first
{
    display: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 220px;
    margin:auto;
    padding-left: 150px;
    margin-top: -215px;

}
#first img 
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#second
{
    display: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 220px;
    margin:auto;
    padding-left: 150px;
    margin-top: -215px;

}
#second img 
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#third
{
    display: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 220px;
    margin:auto;
    padding-left: 150px;
    margin-top: -215px;

}
#third img 
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

 li{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    height: 40px;
    width: 180px;
    text-align:right;    
    border-style: none;

}

.menu{

    width:150px;
    height: 350px;

   }

.menu li{  
position: relative;
  top:150px; 
  bottom: 0;
  left: 695px;
  right:0;
  margin: auto; 
  border-style:none;

}
```

JQUERY:

```
    $(document).on('click','#item1', function()
{ 
    $("#second. #third").fadeOut(2000, function(){
        $("#first").fadeIn(6000);
    });

});


$(document).on('click','#item2', function()
{ 
    $("#first, #third").fadeOut(2000, function(){
        $("#second").fadeIn(6000);
    });
});


$(document).on('click','#item3', function()
{ 
    $("#first, #second").fadeOut(2000, function(){
        $("#third").fadeIn(6000);
    });
});
```

JSFIDDLE:  http://jsfiddle.net/ktyxr77y/

Comment: @Praveen Kumar any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little bit different approach that could be more scaleable: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktyxr77y/7/)

Additionally, to provide a true fadeIn/fadeOut crossfade you can add an `absolute` position to the wrappers (may need to do tweak the placement).

Added CSS:

```
#first, #second, #third { position: absolute;}
```

Jquery:

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
    //get last character of the li
    var lastChar = $(this).attr('id').slice(-1);
    //set which section to change based on the last character of the li's id

    if (lastChar == 1) {
        section = $('#first');
    }
    if (lastChar == 2) {
        section = $('#second');
    }

    if (lastChar == 3) {
        section = $('#third');
    }

    $('#first, #second, #third').not(section).fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $(section).fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

**Note:** I sped up the transitions for the demonstration only.

Comment: they're colliding, the div isn't fading out so that another fade in in its place

Comment: hey man when i added the other four elements, they started colliding.. can i give you the jsfiddle?

Comment: but the key concept of my website is that the divs are centered. Anyway to do so?

Comment: Yep, you can put them all in one big wrapper and center that. Be sure to give it 'position: relative'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81018/discussion-between-randy-and-dwreck08).